# Error in Red Node giving me that application/json is wrong from get request in Node Red js

Tags: node-red

I got this below error from get request

```
Error: expected "Content-Type" matching /json/, got "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

It returned the value as follows :

```
{
    "response": "Learn with Coursera in Manchester"
}
```

Comment: Hi - as this is a question regarding a Coursera assignment, please use the coursera learner forum for help. Make sure you have read the requirements of the assignment properly and the course material that describes how to set the content-type response header properly

Comment: @knolleary , thanks i have already solved the problem and submitted successfully , the thing is that the forum wasnt active and no much posts describe what should i do , does node red have a slack group or forum ?

Comment: When you go to `nodered.org` you will see links to both the Discourse forum and the Slack channel -- as most of us are active on both, there is no need to post your questions to both communities. We use Slack for help with simpler questions, while the forum is for code and design discussions (generally).

Comment: Also if you ask questions about the Coursera course on Slack or the Node-RED Forum you will get the same answer that @knolleary has already given directing you to Coursera Learner forum.

Comment: many thanks for your support:), I am trying to get used to this magnificent tool.